# Extract data from plot using "Brush/Select Data" in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, figure, brush

In my plot I have x-axis in datetime format and y is corresponding observations. There are a few clusters of anomalies which I can visually recognise. I tried to select the anomalies using `Brush/Select data' tool in the figure, but when I tried to copy data on the clipboard and pasted in notepad, the data is not in datetime format and I can not interpret it.

I would like to select the data from plot and remove the indices from the dataset. I am providing a sample of data I copied from brush tool.

```
56.5868518518519    463.32834344035
56.6596759259259    463.337
56.6603240740741    463.335
56.6608217592593    463.326
```

Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at **[rmoutliers(A](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rmoutliers.html))**? If all you need is to remove the outliers this function will do exactly that.

If you for whatever reason cannot use the function, you can use this:

```
% Compute the median absolute difference
meanValue = mean(vector)
% Compute the absolute differences.  It will be a vector.
absoluteDeviation = abs(vector - meanValue)
% Compute the median of the absolute differences
mad = median(absoluteDeviation)
% Find outliers.  They're outliers if the absolute difference
% is more than some factor times the mad value.
sensitivityFactor = 6 % Whatever you want.
thresholdValue = sensitivityFactor * mad;
outlierIndexes = abs(absoluteDeviation) > thresholdValue
% Extract outlier values:
outliers = vector(outlierIndexes)
% Extract non-outlier values:
nonOutliers = vector(~outlierIndexes)%Compute the median absolute difference
```

Credit goes to [this guy](https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/121247-how-can-i-detect-and-remove-outliers-from-a-large-dataset#comment_599658) but its a very simple approach and should do exactly what you need

Comment: thank you @toms for suggesting the function, but the function is only introduced in R2018b. Actually I have written my own algo for outlier detection but these clusters can not be captured by it.

Comment: @phj you should mention which version of matlab you are using

Comment: @pkj I edited my answer and added a code you can use